# Boxplot only showing flat lines

Tags: r, matrix, boxplot

I have the following matrix:

```
test <- matrix(c(2006,100,
                 2007,105,
                 2008,98,
                 2009,102,
                 2010,107),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

And I want to draw its boxplot with

```
boxplot.matrix(test)
```

However, I only get two flat lines:
[image]

I can't pinpoint what I am doing wrong. What could be the problem?

Comment: The variance within each group is really small compared to the difference between the groups, so the box and whiskers are really small on the scale. You could try `boxplot.matrix(test, log = "y")` to transform the y axis, it only improves things slightly though.

Comment: @Marius thanks! So there is no problem, but it's just that the data is actually very homogeneous?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell it's plotting the boxplots fine, it's just they're very squashed on the common scale.

Comment: Is the first column years? If so, you probably don't want to plot it as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the nature of your data, you will see that there are 2 groups that are far apart but within each group, the data points are close together.

Due to the clustering and the scaling, your data appear the way they are.

If you examine each column separately, you will get a "typical" box plot

```
> boxplot(test[,1], main="boxplot of column 1")
```

[image: column1 data]

```
> boxplot(test[,2], main="boxplot of column 2")
```

[image]